# Fullcalendar.js get events of the day on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar, jquery-events

Fullcalendar.js get events of the day on click

Is it possible to get all events of the day I click on in the monthview and print them in any `div` element with `Fullcalendar.js`?

Here's my JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/alexchizhov/syf9ycbc/4/

Answer (score 5):

You can always iterate over all events and find out which event is on selected day. Here is my function to do that:

```
function getEvents(date){
        all_events.forEach(function(entry) {
            if (entry['start'] == date.format()){
                alert(entry['title']);}
            else if (entry['start'] <= date.format() && entry['end'] >= date.format()){
                alert(entry['title']);}
         });

    }
```

You can see my **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/syf9ycbc/7/)**.

If you click on date 2014-10-06 there will be 2 events that will shows up in alert. Click on date 2014-10-07 will alert only one event.

Comment: Thank you! I already did it actually with `moments.js` and `jquery` heres my demo: [http://jsfiddle.net/syf9ycbc/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/syf9ycbc/8/). Now Im looking for the way to highlight days numbers that have events, instead of showing events in the calendar, so user can only see them when clicks on a day.