# How to get all events contents on hour in fullcalendar

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar work correctly,
when I click on event it give me the title of this event.
But What I want is if I have two or three events in one hour, how I can get all title's events ??

for exemple i have two events in 17h, and I want to get the title of them.

[image]

fullcalendar code:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'agendaWeek'
  },
  defaultView:"agendaWeek",
  displayEventTime : false,
  selectable: true,
  selectHelper: true,
  minTime: '08:00:00',
  slotDuration: '00:60:00',
  maxTime: "22:00:00",  
  timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
  contentHeight: 'auto',
  allDaySlot : false,
  timezone : 'local',
  defaultTimedEventDuration : '01:00:00',
  firstDay : 0,
  timeFormat : 'HH:mm',
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  eventOverlap : false,
  eventLimit: true,
  selectOverlap : false,
  events: JSON.parse(json_events),
  eventClick: function(event){
    $('#modalTitle').html("Les Moniteurs dans cette heurs "+datetime);
    $('#fullCalModal').modal();
  },
});
});
```

Comment: by using eventclick() function I can get title of event, but i want to get two events here

Comment: Are fetching  events from database   ? or events are static

Comment: all events are from database

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution, but also check the time part of a date: [Fullcalendar.js get events of the day on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151121/fullcalendar-js-get-events-of-the-day-on-click)